# How to add account in rinkeby test network?

Tags: remix, mist, ethereum-classic, rinkeby, keystore

I have a problem on creating a wallet account.

I have downloaded mist.
I have downloaded ethereum wallet.

I have no idea on anything of this. I am new to this.
I have choosen Develop->Network->Rinkeby Test Network.
I have choosen wallet. I clicked on New Account.
I typed password and confirm password. But it is showing Error as below:

"Make sure you backup your keyfiles AND password

You can find your keyfiles using the main menu -> Accounts -> Backup ->Accounts. Keep a copy of the keystore folder where you can't lose it."

I have on idea now to proceed. Please give detailed suggestions to resolve this problem.

Comment: That should not be an error. That should be a warning. and FYI to deploy contract using Mist and on Ropsten, you need to sync Ropsten Testnet. If this is for testing, I recommend setting up private network

Comment: I don't know about private network, I just followed the tutorial video. Anyhow, please tell me how to sync Ropsten Testnet.

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error. It tells you that you account is created and you should backup your private keys

Comment: Please tell the procedure to back up my private keys. Where they will be present. How should i do?